# My Latitude and Longitude are not changing values when I move locations

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, location

I am trying to show my latitude and longitude as I move around, but it stays at one value and does not change. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? I have already updated the manifest file as well so I'm not sure why it's not working properly. I make calls to it in a writeToFile method in my main activity.

```
package com.explorer.extractor;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;

    //flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    //flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; //location
    double latitude; //latitude
    double longitude; //longitude

    //The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; //10 meters

    //The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 0; //0 minute

    //Declare a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                //no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                //First get location from network provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.i("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        Log.i("NETWORK", "NUMBER 1");
                        if (location != null) {
                            Log.i("NETWORK", "is this not null");
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            Log.i("NETWORK", "THE LATITUDE IS " + latitude);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //if GPS Enabled get lat/long usig GPS services
                else if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    //Function to get Latitude
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    //Function to get longitude
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Log.i("long", "the long is " + longitude);
        }
        Log.i("long", "the long isnt working");
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check if best network provider
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Stop Using GPS Listener
     * Calling this function stops using GPS in app
     */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are using very bad androidhive's tutorial...

Comment: is there one you recommend using instead? @Selvin

Comment: Official android's guide

Answer (score 1):

You should be using onLocationChanged() to update the Lat Longs. With that empty, I'm not sure how often you are actually updating your UI